# Atom でパッケージのインストールに失敗する

Tags: linux, npm, atom-editor

atomでパッケージをインストールする際以下のエラーが出ます。
このエラーの原因は何でしょうか？

```
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error - GET https://www.atom.io/api/packages/hydrogen/versions/2.16.3/tarball

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ryuuta/.atom/.apm/_logs/2022-04-18T23_47_16_086Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

どうやらサーバー関連の不具合っぽいです。待つしかなさそうですね。

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/25417

Comment: 確認したら確かにサーバーエラーが出ましたAnonymousの攻撃かなんかなんでしょうねありがとうございます。